# How can I add background image on sidebar menu with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have following code below I want it to have background for all of them just one image but I couldn't:

```
  drawer: new Drawer(
    child: new ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        //header
        InkWell(
          //click özelliği burada back-end sonra yapılacak
          onTap:(){},
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text("Little Sister's Farm"),
            leading: Icon(Icons.wb_sunny,color: Colors.orangeAccent),
            subtitle: Text('Deneme@gmail.com'),
          ),
        ),

// yan tarafta açılan sidebar menü
        
    new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: Text('Kullanıcı Adı'),
                accountEmail: Text('deneme@gmail.com'),
              decoration:
              new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage("images/wood.jpg"),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover)
              ),
            ),
// body
            InkWell(
              //click özelliği burada back-end sonra yapılacak
              onTap:(){},
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Kayıt/Giriş'),
                leading: Icon(Icons.person_add,color: Colors.blueGrey),
              ),
            ),

          InkWell(
            //click özelliği burada back-end sonra yapılacak
            onTap:(){},
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text('Anasayfa'),
              leading: Icon(Icons.home,color: Colors.green),
            ),
          ),
            InkWell(
              onTap:(){},
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Hesabım'),
                leading: Icon(Icons.account_box,color: Colors.deepPurple),
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap:(){},
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Siparişlerim'),
                leading: Icon(Icons.fastfood,color: Colors.tealAccent),
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap:(){},
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Kategoriler'),
                leading: Icon(Icons.dashboard,color: Colors.orange),
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap:(){},
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Favoriler'),
                leading: Icon(Icons.favorite,color: Colors.red),
              ),
            ),
            Divider(),
            InkWell(
              onTap:(){},
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Ayarlar'),
                leading: Icon(Icons.settings,color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap:(){},
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Yardım'),
                leading: Icon(Icons.help_outline,color: Colors.yellow),
              ),
            ),

            InkWell(
              //click özelliği burada back-end sonra yapılacak
              onTap:(){},
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Lokasyon'),
                leading: Icon(Icons.location_city,color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Stack() widget and put your background image and drawer items in it.

```
Drawer(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset("your image adress"),
            ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                // your Drawer Items
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
```